# setInterval keeps running after ngDestroy and route change in Ionic 5

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic5

I have a modal (page) with this following functions:

```
  private countdownTime : number = 20;
  private logoutCountdown : any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startLogout();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    clearInterval(this.logoutCountdown);
  }

  startLogout(){
    this.logoutCountdown = setInterval(() => {
      this.countdownTime--;
      console.log(this.countdownTime);
      if (this.countdownTime == 0) {
        this.logout();
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  closeModal(){
    clearInterval(this.logoutCountdown);
    this.modal.dismiss();
  }

  logout(){
    clearInterval(this.logoutCountdown);
    this.modal.dismiss();
    this.auth.logout().then();
  }
```

After 20 seconds it closes but still running setInterval in another route, there is a reason to clearInterval not working in this page? This have some relation with PageModule of modal being in app.module.ts imports?

Comment: After looking at your code, it's not apparent what is wrong. Only thing I can think is that you're accidentally creating multiple instances of your modal or something. You could try extracting the `logoutCountdown` and `countdownTime` variables into a singleton service so that you can be sure there's only ever one interval running at a time.

Comment: do you have a stackblitz? your code looks like it should work

Comment: does ngOnDestroy actually get called? did yo uchecked that for your modal? in Ionic modals are not truly lazy loading, they are loading as part of the module they are part of. So they might persist in memory till the module that hosts modal is destroyed.